# Get TypeError when trying to get all Rows from MySql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm semi new to Python and need some help. Didn't find much from googling. I'm using pymysql with python3. I can connect and query my db. When I try to get all the rows in a table and loop over them I get the erro `TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface`.

```
query = conn.cursor()
query.execute("SELECT * FROM wp_options")
for row in query:
    print(row)
query.close()
```

The table contains strings and integers. Ideally I want to loop over each row and search for a value but right now I'm unable to even get the row. Looks like the exception is being thrown from `struct.unpack` in `unpack_int24`. Any help would be greatly apprecaited

**EDIT**

After some problem solving I discovered that one column is `longtext`. Every other one works fine with this code. If I try to get all the rows from the field that is longtext then it errors. Why does Longtext in mysql cause a python error?

Comment: Was able to get the code to work using `"SELECT CAST(option_value AS CHAR(255)) FROM wp_options"` Still curious why longtext causes an error.

Comment: I think this only worked cuz it limited the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use `rows = query.fetchall()` (or fetchone() or fecthmany(n)) on your query object (after executing the query) to return row on which you will now iterate:

```
query = conn.cursor()
query.execute("SELECT * FROM wp_options")
rows = query.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
query.close()
```

Comment: Tried the suggestion. Still getting the error. Seems like it's the execute function that is getting the error since If I just do execute and no loops I still get it.

Comment: Are you sure that the cursor object is successfully formed? Are you sure wp_options is a valid table name in your database?

Comment: The table is valid because in the function before it I pull a field out of the table and that works fine. Seems to be fine with a single field but not with rows that can contain ints and strs

Comment: my code works but the error is caused when trying to get fields that are `longtext` format in mysql. Any ideas? Additionally I read that the cursor returns all without needing to do a fetchall so either way works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I found. 
The issue was arising when I was trying to query records that had a `longtext` column with a lot of data. The issue is part of the mysql adapter I'm using `pymysql`

Looks like in Python3 unpack_24, unpack_32, unpack_64 all fail since they get bytes and not strings like python2. The long data throws an error and there is no exception handling. Solution was found here http://code.google.com/p/pymysql/issues/detail?id=55